# How do repeated disjuncts with back-references work?

Tags: .net, regex

Given a regex like

```
(a|b){2}\1
```

What will `\1` refer to? The first capture, the last capture, or what?

```
Regex.IsMatch("aba", @"^(?:(a|b){2}\1)$") == False
Regex.IsMatch("abb", @"^(?:(a|b){2}\1)$") == True
```

Leads me to suspect it matches the *last* capture. I'm I correct in this assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guessed right. Java does this, too. Most (if not all) regex engines store the last capture for repeated groups.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#repeat for a general description.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719621%28v=VS.71%29.aspx for a confirmation regarding .Net:

> "[...] when a group makes multiple captures, a backreference refers to the most recent capture."