# How should I refactor this regex-reversal algorithm to allow repeating character classes?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I wrote [this algorithm](http://code.google.com/p/revex/source/browse/trunk/Revex/RegexTools/Revex.cs#39) to generate a string that a regex will match. Works really well, but it's still missing a couple features.

For example, when reversing `\d{3}` it first chooses a number, and then repeats that same number 3 times. I'd like to choose 3 different numbers.

I think the easiest way to solve this problem would be to push the `\d` onto the token list and evaluate it *after* the quantifier, rather than before.

That's all fine and dandy, but how about parsing things like `(a(b)){2}|(c)\3`. Assuming I'm following the "evaluate later" strategy, this would be tokenized into "`(a(b))`,`(a(b))` or `(c)`,`\3`". Which actually leads to a few problems. I can't just treat `(a(b))` as a whole chunk and repeat it, I actually have to evaluate it sometime before `\3` so that I can count the numbered references (`ab` is `\1`, `b` is `\2`, and `c` is `\3`).

The other problem is that if I actually repeat the strings like that, `(a(b))`,`(a(b))` twice... then when I go to number it, it will be double-counted since I've lost the quantifier information. Unless I don't keep a list of strings, but rather a more complicated structure that indicates if its been counted or not. That, or I stuff it into the back-reference list immediately... but if I put it in unevaluated, it will need to be evaluated twice, which won't work, so I'd have to evaluate it before putting it into the back-reference list...

But then if I have something like `(a|b){2}\1`? I [*think*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381762/how-do-repeated-disjuncts-with-back-references-work) the `\1` refers to the *last* capture. So I can't evaluate `(a|b)` immediately and then throw the result in the back-reference list because it might be quantified... I can perhaps evaluate it immediately after quantifying.

I was thinking [a different structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381630/how-to-build-an-and-or-tree) would help me with all this. But I still don't know how to factor in the quantifiers... I was just going to duplicate the nodes immediately when a quantifier is found, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach. Maybe if I add repeat-min, repeat-max variables onto the node?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are at the limit of what a regular expression can do.  I think what you need to do is classic parsing, generate a parse tree from your input string and then in a tree analysis step do the type of analyses you talk about in your post.

Comment: So you agree that I need a tree structure... ok. I'm going to play around with this for a bit and see what I can come up with.